# Missing $scope.$apply in then statement - Having to run it manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to centralize the data service that passes all of the information back and forth between my application and the back-end services.

My application does not auto-bootstrap using ng-app="myApp", instead it loads the few modules it needs to load an external config file, and use that to get the initial data from the server before bootstrapping the application.  Once the application gets bootstrapped, the feeds are assigned to the main controllers scope via `$scope[feedName] = feedData`.  Because the feeds may vary, I've done this to ensure that the data is available to all scopes at all times.

Since I need to be able to use resource efficiently in this pre-bootstrapped scenario, I wrote a small function to get data called `getDataFrom(url, data, method)`.

It looks like this:

```
getDataFrom = function(url, data, method){
    // Create the resource object to get the data using the supplied parameters
        var getData = $resource(url, $.extend(data, {"callback": "JSON_CALLBACK"}), {query: {method: method}});

    // Return the promise immediately
        return getData.query().$promise;
};
```

It works perfectly in this scenario.  Now, before I bootstrap my application, I assign a few constants, and this function is one of them:

`app.constant("getDataFrom", getDataFrom);`

Then whenever a module needs to send/receive data it is included as a dependency:

`.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $sanitize, getDataFrom)`

From here I can simply make a call like this:

`getDataFrom(myUrl, {myData:equalsThis}, "JSON").then(result){//do stuff})`

The problem I am having happens inside the `then` part of this scenario.  If I do anything involving the scope, such as `$location.path('/newpath')` or `$scope.value = newValue`, none of this will happen unless I manually run `$scope.$apply()`.  Since this is supposed to be an easy way of handling data, this clearly won't cut it.

Can somebody please explain to me why my `then` is missing the bus of the `$scope.$apply` that gets run automatically?

How this is getting called:

```
getDataFrom(
        $scope.app.services.myService, 
        {"myData": input.val()}
        , "JSON")
.then(function(result){
    if (result.data && result.data.length > 0){
        $scope.results = result.data;
        list.show();
    }
})
```

Comment: You know you could just return `getData.query().$promise` since it is a promise object, no need to create a whole new deferred

Comment: @PatrickEvans Would that solve my problem, what code would I then use in place of the resolve and reject currently there?

Comment: I believe $promise is processed within a digest cycle, you would have to test to make sure. As for the resolve/reject, just remove that code and just do: `return getData.query().$promise;`

Comment: Ah ok I got it now.  That doesn't fix the problem but it is much cleaner.

Comment: Calling out to an injected method shouldn't affect whether the digest cycle happens automatically. I think we need to know how you are triggering the code in your controller that makes the call to `getDataFrom()`.

Comment: @DanaCartwright  Added an example usage to the bottom of the question.

Comment: OK. What I was asking was more whether you are calling getDataFrom() directly in the controller function, or from your UI in some way. Is it called when the controller initializes, or, for example, when a button is clicked?

Comment: It's used in many ways, two of which is via a button click calling a function which calls it, and another one is inside a keystroke sequence that checks against what's input then calls for autocomplete results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the $resource service you could just do

```
return getData.query();
```

$resource actions return a empty object/array (depending on what you set isArray to) that will be filled when the request has resolved.

So if your service was

```
getDataFrom = function(url, data, method){
    var getData = $resource(url, 
        $.extend(data, {
            "callback": "JSON_CALLBACK"
        }), {
            query: {method: method}
        }
    );
    return getData.query();
};
```

in your controller you could then simply do

```
$scope.someVar = getDataFrom(/*...*/);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f1mgdkep/)

If you still need to do other work after the request has finished just access $promise from the object

```
$scope.someVar.$promise.then(function(){
    /* do other stuff */
});
```

Comment: This is literally exactly what I was already doing, except you moved the $promise from the return to the calling function.  It also results in the same problem sadly.

Comment: This is not at all what you were doing, this doesnt use the promise at all, i just said you could still use it, but you dont have to.